# How to fix " dereferencing NULL pointer" even though the pointer is not null?

Tags: c

I have the code bellow that keeps giving this error "dereferencing a null pointer" but the pointer is not supposed to be null

```
char* foo(char* str, int* x) {
    *x = strlen(str);
    char* str2 = malloc((*x+1)*sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < *x; i++)
        str2[i] = str[*x - i];//I get the error here for str2
return str2;
}
```

I have tried print `sizeof(str2)` but it always says 4 no matter how much memory I allocate
so, what is the problem and how can i solve it?
this is how i call the function:

```
int main()
{
    char* str = "hello";
    int l=1;
    foo(str,&l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It probably wants you to add a check of your `malloc` result.

Comment: Since `str2` is a pointer, `sizeof` reports the size of the pointer. Use `strlen` to determine the length of the string (excluding the terminating null character)

Comment: `x` may be `NULL`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Then the warning would be on the second line. Well, sure it can, but I guess the static analyzer knows more than us about this code :)

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: I suspect you left out the needed headers and ignored the warnings.  With them added, your code compiles and works fine.